# How to bind a collection to Extended WPF Toolkit's DropdownButton?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, wpftoolkit

I'm trying to create a SIMPLE dropdownlist/combobox with a title/header. I repeat **SIMPLE**. I found this pretty `DropdownButton` in Extended WPF Toolkit [here](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DropDownButton&referringTitle=Home). The problem is.. It does not contain anything like `ItemsSource` or `DataSource`, so I can't even bind my collection = I can't use MVVM pattern (which doesn't make sense in WPF). Am I missing something here?

Here's the example of my "goal" using `ComboBox`

```
            <ComboBox Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding MyOptions}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding DisplayName}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
```

This example is almost perfect, but I can't specify a header in ComboBox with simple `Header="Check your options:"`.

**The question is: How can I bind a collection from ViewModel to `DropdownButton` control?**

Thanks,

Comment: I think the goal would be you put a Menu (or whatevs) in the DropDownContent and bind its ItemsSource to your list.  You can bind a Command to each pointing back to your ViewModel that takes the current item as its CommandParameter.  When the user clicks, do whatevs you need to do.

Comment: The link you posted itself is telling us _you can place any custom content_ in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution could be:

```
            <wpfTool:DropDownButton Content="Options">
                <wpfTool:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
                    <ListView Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding MyOptions}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Content="{Binding DisplayName}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </wpfTool:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
            </wpfTool:DropDownButton>
```